# Hide column in ngx-datatable Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ngx-datatable

I'm new to [NGX-datatable](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable). I have to populate my data table from Firebase in my ionic app. Given below is the format of [JSON](https://www.json.org/) which is returned from the Firebase.

I want to know if I don't use the User_id as a column, how do I access the User_id in the row button click event? Or in the other hand, how can I use the User_Id as a column how to hide User_Id column. How can I achieve this?

```
{
User_id:data,
User_name:data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find here on how to toggle columns in ngx-datatable

```
toggle(col) {
    const isChecked = this.isChecked(col);
    if(isChecked) {
      this.columns = this.columns.filter(c => { 
        return c.name !== col.name; 
      });
    } else {
      this.columns = [...this.columns, col];
    }
  }
```

**[GITHUB DEMO](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/columns/column-toggle.component.ts)**